# Unable to get next record from result set. IO Error: Socket read timed out

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish

This error message is come from when running a jasper report more than around 15 minute will show.
I am using :

```
Glassfish 5.0
JAVA 8
Oracle Database
```

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unable to get next record from result set.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Socket read timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Socket read timed out
```

Anybody can to resolve either set in glassfish or change in java code.
I have apllied `conn.setNetworkTimeout(executor, 3600000)` in code but not seem to work